# Why is the for loop not getting executed?

Tags: php, for-loop

I wanted to try out and make a Diamond Pattern Out Of My Name in PHP.
My Code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: gourab
 * Date: 20/7/15
 * Time: 10:35 PM
 */
$name = "GOURAB";
$revName = strrev($name);
$len = strlen($name);

for($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++)
{
    echo substr($name, $i)
        . str_repeat(" ", $i)
        . str_repeat(" ", $i)
        . substr($revName, $i)
        . "\n";
}
for($j = $len; $j <= 1; $j--)
{
    echo substr($name, $j)
        . str_repeat(" ", $j)
        . str_repeat(" ", $j)
        . substr($revName, $j)
        . "\n";
}
```

The first for Loop that is `for($i = 0, $i <= 0; $i++)` works fine and creates the first part of the diamond.

Output of the First Part:

```
GOURABBARUOG
OURAB  ARUOG
URAB    RUOG
RAB      UOG
AB        OG
B          G
```

But the second for loop `for($j = $len; $j <= 1; $j--)` dosen't get executed at all. I debugged it in PHPStrom and it showed no signs of executing the for loop when I added the Break Point in the second for loop.

Can Any body tell me what the problem is?

Any help would be appreciated.

**CHEERS!!!**

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't execute?

Comment: Cause' when i set a breakpoint in the second for loop the IDE does not execute the inside part of that for loop!

Comment: Because your condition does not satisfy. i.e. `$j <= 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($j = $len; $j <= 1; $j--)
```

look at this code, `$j` is equal to `$len, $len` is greater than 1 and you create loop `$j <= 1` - so until `$j` is less or equal than 1. `$j` is higher so loop its not executed

so try again to set `$j = $len; $j >= 1; $j--`

Comment: Thanks it really helped me understand a lot!

Answer (score 3):

try to change:

```
for($j = $len; $j <= 1; $j--)
```

to:

```
for($j = $len; $j >= 1; $j--)
```